# yii can't access Yii::$app->params ( return null value) in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am using yii2 advanced template.

I can't access Yii::$app->params from my user model.
I get a null value in return .

Here is my main.php in frontend/config ( i use advanced template).

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/params-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/functions.php')
);

return [
    'id' => 'app-frontend',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        /*
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
            ],
        ],
        */
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];
```

Comment: Have you tried to print out the `params` object? `var_dump(Yii::$app->params);`

Answer (score 1):

Params are set in `config/params.php`/`config/params-local.php`, and accessible through `Yii::$app->params['key']`.

I not sure how your 'functions.php' looks, but this works out of the box with 'adminEmail'. Params are values stored in an array, and your `functions.php` should not haves functions or any other logic. Try removing your functions.php from the array_merge, and try with this:

**Eksample** (already defined in Yii2 Advanced app)

```
<?= Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'] ?>
```